# Self-contained python application with GUI and charts

Tags: python, windows, sqlite, user-interface

I have some data in an SQLite database and serve it through JSON objects to an HTML app via AJAX calls and chart it using D3.js. I would like to replicate the same functionality locally (MS Windows is fine) in a *self-contained* application. It would be a super simple app, just a few form controls, a chart and a table, querying a local file-based database. As for it being self-contained - I'd like to ship an .exe file and an .sqlite file to someone with no need to install python, numpy, matplotlib, sqlite or anything on the target computer.

I'd like to it to be quite future-proof, so I'd rather stay away from experimental/alpha libraries and build it using more proven technologies that have had longer term support. It seems that PyInstaller is the way to go in terms of self-containing, but developers seem to be quite divided when it comes to GUI options.

The question is then: What's the industry standard to build future self-contained GUI apps in Python? One which would include SQLite access and charting. Thanks!

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: And when do you, I have a sneaking suspicion that it will be put on hold because *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."*

Comment: Apologies, I specified a more concrete question now. Should it be too vague or general, feel free to delete this post. I've tried doing some research, but there seem to be a lot of options, many of them abandoned or unstable, hence the question. But I understand if it doesn't fit Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Python itself includes the sqlite module since version 2.5:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

So regardless of which Python GUI Toolkit you go with, you already have that functionality built in to Python. There are several options to choose from when it comes to Python GUI toolkits. If you want a toolkit that can handle theming / skinning, then you may want to look at [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) or even [Kivy](http://kivy.org/). The only GUI toolkit that uses the actual widgets of each major OS that I know of is [wxPython](http://wxpython.org/). All the others draw their own widgets, albeit some of them do it so well that you'd be hard-pressed to tell the difference (i.e. PyQt).

All three of these projects are stable and are currently being developed, although wxPython's development is much slower than the others mentioned here. wxPython and PyQt both have widgets that allow you to load web pages.

However if all you want to do is serve web pages locally, then you might be better served using a Python web framework such as [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). You could run these locally pretty easily and view your content via the user's browser. The exe could launch them locally and call Python's [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) module to launch the default browser to a local URL.